# User defined function inside standard SUMIFS formula

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I have written a function that checks cell to be crossed out:

```
Function isCrossedout(myRange As Range)
    isCrossedout = myRange.Font.Strikethrough
End Function
```

and I have a column "A:A" of numbers where I want to sum up crossed out elements only.

Can I insert in any cell the standard function SUMIFS with my user defined function?
When I try this:

```
someCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS('Page'!RC1:RC1, isCrossedout)"
```

it returns zero value when the formula applied.

I realize there is a way to use summing such cells in a pure VBA way with a loop, but I want to try to use it with Excel SUMIFS formula.

Comment: Your function requires a single parameter containing the cell/range to check. You are missing that from your formula.

Comment: Probably should use `SUMPRODUCT`. Also I doubt `isCrossedout` is going to work as is - you need an array of booleans. `Font.Strikethrough` won't return an array.

Comment: Also a note.  If the strike through is because of conditional formatting this method will not work.

Comment: Also `'Page'!RC1:RC1` is returning one cell.  The cell in column `A` in the row in which the formula is placed.  That may be what you want.

Comment: if you want a single cell then an `IF` would be best: `someCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF( isCrossedout('Page'!RC1:RC1),'Page'!RC1:RC1,0)"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need `isCrossedout` to return a boolean *array*. [`Font.Strikethrough`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.font.strikethrough) will not return an array, so use a loop:

```
Function isCrossedout(ByVal myRange As Range) As Boolean()
    Dim arr() As Boolean
    ReDim arr(1 To myRange.Rows.Count, 1) ' assumes myRange has one column
    
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In myRange
        Dim counter As Long
        counter = counter + 1
        
        arr(counter, 1) = cell.Font.Strikethrough
    Next
    
    isCrossedout = arr
End Function
```

Next, I'd use `SUMPRODUCT`, with the double unary `--` to coerce the boolean array to an array of ones and zeros.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A5*--isCrossedout(A2:A5))
```

[image]

For a version that can handle a multi-column input:

```
Function isCrossedout(myRange As Range) As Boolean()
    Dim arr() As Boolean
    ReDim arr(1 To myRange.Rows.Count, 1 To myRange.Columns.Count)
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To myRange.Columns.Count
            arr(i, j) = myRange.Cells(i, j).Font.Strikethrough
        Next
    Next
    
    isCrossedout = arr
End Function
```

[image]